# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Collection')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Today I was coding a small discord.js music bot, but then i got an error and I don't really know how to fix it. Anyone know a fix?

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUWT1.png)

and this is my code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { discord, Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const myIntents = new Intents();
myIntents.add(Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES);

const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents });
const { Player } = require('discord-player');

client.player = new Player(client);
client.config = require('./config/bot');
client.emotes = client.config.emojis;
client.filters = client.config.filters;
client.commands = new discord.Collection();

fs.readdirSync('./commands').forEach(dirs => {
    const commands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dirs}`).filter(files => files.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of commands) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${dirs}/${file}`);
        console.log(`Loading command ${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name.toLowerCase(), command);
    };
});

const events = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const player = fs.readdirSync('./player').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of events) {
    console.log(`Loading discord.js event ${file}`);
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    client.on(file.split(".")[0], event.bind(null, client));
};

for (const file of player) {
    console.log(`Loading discord-player event ${file}`);
    const event = require(`./player/${file}`);
    client.player.on(file.split(".")[0], event.bind(null, client));
};

client.login(client.config.discord.token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Error originiates from this particular line

```js
 client.commands.set(command.name.toLowerCase(), command);
```

Why? because of this:

```js
const { discord, Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
```

So you are trying to destructure `discord` from discord.js which is not available to the module, as you can see below the discord.js module has the following functions and properties:
[image: components of discord.js]

Now if you want to **destructure** it you have to get the `Collection` itself instead of `discord` and then further `discord.Collection`. At the very top of your file you are destructuring some components from the module discord.js so you very well need to destructure the `Collection` too! like so:

```js
    const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError, Collection } = require('discord.js');     
    // then you may define it like so    
    client.commands = new Collection()    

   // then you may further use 
    client.commands.set(command.name.toLowerCase(), command);
```

This would be absolutely valid as you can see here:
[image: display]

Comment: okay so i edited it but i'm getting [this error now](https://imgur.com/a/ItHfMOj) @Zero

Comment: Did you add that at the top of your file? If yes then you don't need to redeclare it you have to edit it in your current code make sure everything is below where you define client ( const client = new Client() )

Comment: yes, i did.
Now i'm getting a different [error](https://imgur.com/a/q16cnOM) | 

[this is my code](https://pastebin.com/xMe4DkXW)

Comment: It seems you are still getting confused, [this would be your final code](https://sourceb.in/8Zhecy9cSj)

Comment: thank you @Zero, the bot works now |

Edit: so i was testing the bot, and [this happened](https://imgur.com/a/AtMrsG7)

Comment: Glad it helped!  make sure to add an upvote using the  button and accept the answer using ✓ icon, refer to [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info!

Comment: saw your edit, error originates from nowplaying.js if you are trying to rewrite the code in v13 it is recommended that you change it as whole

Comment: how can i change it exactly?

Comment: Changing it as in rewriting the bot in whole